# how to speed up dumping mermory from memory to GPU?

Tags: opengl, gpu, gpgpu, ogre

I am developing something AR(augmented reality) on PC, I have cameras capturing,certain marker features detected, and dumps the memory to GPU to render virtual objects on the image. I use Ogre engine.

```
/** Convenience function that blits a pixelbox from memory to the entire 
            buffer. The source image is scaled as needed.
            @param src      PixelBox containing the source pixels and format in memory
            @note Only call this function when the buffer is unlocked. 
        */
 mTexture->getBuffer()->blitFromMemory(mPixelBox);
```

for a 720P image input, it takes around 100ms, which is undesired for rendering. I have a i5-4460 @ 3.20GHz,16G memory and Geforce GTX 660 card.

I know there's gap between CPU and GPU memory, but what if I just showing 720P video inputs with amcap which is just 30fps. is anything appears on the screen render from GPU? how to know the speed of CPU and GPU memory?

Comment: not sure what this has to do with cuda

Comment: This blitFromMemory looks like a heavy solution (scales the texture...). Look for a way to load the texture more directly, like when it comes from a file.

Comment: If you want to render virtual objects on screen you maybe should look at a graphics library like OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

To do this efficiently, you really need to be able to tolerate a couple of frames latency.

At 100ms, that is effectively 2 extra frames when drawing at 30 FPS. This behavior may be explainable by the driver queuing up multiple frames ahead of time.

A driver setting called pre-rendered frames (NVIDIA) / flip queue size (AMD) will increase latency on any data transferred between the CPU and GPU. 3 is the default on AMD drivers and it is not clear what NVIDIA's default is (but the numbers you are discussing suggest it is also 3). Try setting it to 1, which will limit CPU/GPU parallelism (potentially lower framerate) but will give you the lowest latency possible.

There is a reason drivers do not ship with this set to 1 though, which brings me back to my original point. Try to accept a couple of frames worth of latency and everything will run a lot more smoothly - you very likely are not running into I/O transfer limits here, just parallelism issues.

Comment: This all depends on how you're measuring the amount of time taken to upload the image data. I don't know how Ogre does this, but in GL if you used a fence sync object to detect when the upload is finished, what I just described would affect the numbers reported.